# Moshi can't deserialize Map with List of values, returns LinkedHashTreeMap instead of value's class instance

Tags: java, json, moshi

Can't deserialize json to this structure: `Map<String, List<SomeClass>>`

I can deserialize to `Map<String, SomeClass>` like this:

```
ParameterizedType type = Types.newParameterizedType(Map.class, String.class, SomeClass.class);
JsonAdapter<Map<String, SomeClass>> adapter = moshi.adapter(type);
```

But when there are two collections nested, for example, `Map<String, List<SomeClass>>`, the next code

```
ParameterizedType type = Types.newParameterizedType(Map.class, String.class, List.class, SomeClass.class);
JsonAdapter<Map<String, List<SomeClass>>> adapter = moshi.adapter(type);
```

returns `Map<String, List<LinkedHashTreeMap>>`, `LinkedHashTreeMap` has properties of `SomeClass` as keys and their values as values, and `"type"="SomeClass"`.

How can I solve this, so that deserialization runs okay, as in the first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that to deserialize nested collections we have to pass nested parametrized types to the adapter. After changing this

```
ParameterizedType type = Types.newParameterizedType(Map.class, String.class, List.class, baseType);
```

to this

```
ParameterizedType type = Types.newParameterizedType(Map.class, String.class, Types.newParameterizedType(List.class, baseType));
```

I now have a working solution - I get a `Map` with `List<SomeClass>` values not `LinkedHashTreeMap`s.

Comment: Ah, yes. Parameterized types can be tricky. Maybe Moshi should fail with an error message when it receives a Map<Type, Type, Type> or similar by accident. Glad you got it working.